# Rails - Docker Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have sample ROR application( ruby 2.2.3 and rails 4.2.6 ) with Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.2.3
FROM rails:4.2.6
ENV INSTALL_PATH /home/projects/sample_ror_files
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
ADD Gemfile /home/projects/sample_ror_files/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /home/projects/sample_ror_files/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . $INSTALL_PATH
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

When I try to `docker build -t test_image .` I am getting following error message.

> Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3
>   The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 18

I have installed many ruby version in my system but currently choosen 2.2.3 and I am also getting 2.2.3 when run `ruby -v`

I am not sure what was the issue...

Comment: I don't think you can inherit from several images yet (see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24445). Maybe, inherit from ruby, then install rails on this image ?